# media attribute question for the source element HTML5

Tags: html

can some one list or provide a link to all the possible values for the source elements media attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of media attributes for the source tag here:
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_source_media.asp

Unfortunately it seems that no major browsers currently support the media attribute for the source tag.